# Php contact form coding issue

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I am having trouble with the contact form that I've created for my website. I am not a PHP expert but I thought a proper contact form would be more professional than a simple href mailto link.
I managed to get the email, it tells me the sender but there is no subject and is all just blank without text. Also I keep receiving 2 emails everyday from no sender.

This is what I done in PHP in the page named contact.php. 
I hope you can help:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$form1_services = $_POST['form1_services'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "dandrea.alessandro81@gmail.com";
$subject = "Customer Inquiry";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You! Keep in touch soon!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'           style='text-decoration:none;font-family: 'gooddogregular';color:#009999;'>     Return Home</a>";
```

?>

And this is the actual form in HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="controlgroup">
            <label for="form1_name">Name *</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name*" name="name" value>
        </div>
        <div class="controlgroup">
            <label for="form1_email">Email *</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a valid email address*" name="email" value>
        </div>
        <div class="controlgroup">
            <label for="form1_services">Services Required</label>
                <select id="form1_services" name="services">
                    <option value="Website Design"> Website Design (from scratch) </option>
                    <option value="Resposive Design"> Responsive Design </option>
                    <option value="Customize a Site"> Customize a Site </option>
                    <option value="Quotation"> Quotation </option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="controlgroup">
            <label>Project Info*</label>
                <textarea placeholder="Ciao Alessandro, I am contacting you because...*" id="msg" name="msg" required aria-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="send" value="Hit me up!" class="wow rubberBand animated" data-wow-delay="2s">
    </fieldset>         
</form>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
Alessandro

Comment: Add `echo('<p>'.$_POST['name'].'</p>');` to your php to make sure you are actually getting data from the form.

Comment: As a cautionary tale, as @samlev is mentioning, you need to implement validation so someone doesn't hijack your form to send spam.

Comment: Also watch that you're using the index coming from the `name` html attribute. You're asking for `$_POST['form1_services']` but it's actually sent as `services`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your PHP, you're collecting a number of fields, and then not actually using them. Try this:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$form1_services = $_POST['services'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

$message = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\n";
$message .= 'Service: ' . $form1_services . "\n";
$message .= 'Message: ' . "\n";
$message .= $msg;

$recipient = "dandrea.alessandro81@gmail.com";
$subject = "Customer Inquiry";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You! Keep in touch soon!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'           style='text-decoration:none;font-family: 'gooddogregular';color:#009999;'>     Return Home</a>";
```

Keep in mind that at this point, you're not actually validating any of this information, so you can't be sure that the email address or the name is actually valid at all, but this should at least show you what is getting posted.

Comment: Hi samlev, thanks a lot for your help. I just tried your code and is finally working. the only thing is that the email goes to my junk..do you think it could be fixed?

Comment: The best option there is to not have it come 'from' the user (that's prone to abuse, and most mail clients will see that the sender doesn't match the server that actually sent it). You're getting the name and email in the body, so just send it from your own email address, or you could set up a gmail filter which catches all the contact requests.

Comment: I'll also note that having the unsanitized `from` as a header is bad news. I could set my email address to `test@example.com\r\nBCC: spamtarget@example.com, spamtarget2@example.com, morespam@example.com` and then it would email multiple other people without you realising.

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, please tick the answer as correct answer, if it really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some headers:

```
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    $mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```